# Как в awx автоматически подтягивать хосты с файла inventory с репозитория на гитлабе

Tags: gitlab, awx

Не могу сделать автоматическую подгрузку файла inventory c гитлаба в awx. Захожу в инвенторис, создаю инвентори. Потом иду во вкладку sources (в том же inventory), создаю source, в него прописываю какой файл, откуда взять. Сперва не заполнял credentials. Оно мне закономерно выдало ошибку что "ERROR! Attempting to decrypt but no vault secrets found". Понятно, нужен vault ключ. Добавил в список credentials vault ключ. Вовзращаюсь к source, и нажимаю добавить credentials. И оно не видит ни одного credentials (у меня есть около 4 кредов, от гитлаба, от волта и ещё что-то там). Т.е. волт ключ есть, в шаблоне он виден. При запуске шаблона все работает хорошо. Но в source по прежнему не видно ни одного creds. Как на скриншоте:

[image: Нет ключей]
[image: Вот здесь видно что ключи есть]

Answer (score 0):

Это связано с багом в awx. Для того чтобы решить эту проблему необходимо создать отдельный project который будет указывать на файл inventory. После этого, необходимо синхронизировать source, и он подтянет все хосты